# is there a better way to have helpers in angular2

Tags: angular

is there a better way to have helpers in angular2?

For example, I have a function called slug, which converts text to slug. Right now I have it in the same class where i use it.

Is there a way to have it globally, so i can use it in any component or service across the application?

Answer (score 1):

Project organization is a big topic, but basically you can export things from one file and import them into another.

If you only have a few helpers for now, you might put them in a file like `shared/helpers.ts` for now. If they continue to grow, you might split them out into separate files grouping them by purpose. Something like, maybe putting custom validators in their own file.

So in `shared/helpers.ts` you might have something that looks like:

```
export function myHelper(someParam) {
  // Do your stuff

  }
```

Then just import it in whatever file you're going to use it in.

```
import {myHelper} from './shared/helpers';
```